# Convert data type in select statement using cast

Tags: sql, oracle, select, casting

I have the following query

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(A.OVERTIME as float)) 
FROM DUTY_TRAN1 A,DUTY_MAS B 
WHERE A.DOC_NO=B.DOC_NO 
  AND A.FROM_DATE='01-JAN-18' 
  AND A.TO_DATE='31-JAN-18'
```

A.OVERTIME is in varchar. I wish to convert it in float or int in order for SUM function to work. I get error as invalid number.

Sample data of varchar column

[image]

Comment: Are you using Oracle Database or MySQL?

Comment: @JSapkota Iam using Oracle database

Comment: Could you provide us some sample data from the varchar2 column?

Comment: Are those blanks white spaces or null?

Comment: @JSapkota I have added a screenshot of sample data of varchar column, some of the data are not available, I tried using NVL but no vail

Comment: @JSapkota There is no data for that record , so NVL should work I suppose

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers in a `VARCHAR` in the first place

Comment: What is `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` set to in your session?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37478848/266304) if the answer to my previous comment is `',.'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `OVERTIME`  has non-numeric characters such as space/alphanumeric in some of the columns. First step is to identify them.

A query using `translate` will yield all the characters you cannot find in a decimal number.

```
SELECT * FROM  DUTY_TRAN1 A WHERE translate (OVERTIME,'x.+-0123456789','x') 
IS NOT NULL;
```

The above query will return the rows that contain anything other than numbers, a "." and  "+/-"  symbols. This will work if your string has one "." character. For a comprehensive test with decimal in Oracle versions up to 12.1 , you may have to use a REGXP_ or a user defined function. Refer the below link:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Then, you may exclude them from `WHERE` clause so that the `SUM` works only with numeric characters.

```
with t(n)
AS
(
  select '1.5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select '.6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select '22.5'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'a'  FROM DUAL
  )
select  SUM (CAST ( n  AS FLOAT ) ) 
FROM t WHERE translate (n,'x+-.0123456789','x') 
IS  NULL;
```

If you are running  Oracle 12.2,  You can specify the `DEFAULT return_value ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause in `CAST`.

```
CAST(OVERTIME 
       AS FLOAT
       DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR)
```

[**CAST**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75)

Last but not the least, an important advice to you is to use the ANSI standard of `JOIN ON` syntax rather than the obsolete `tablea,tableb` syntax for joins